# Using parameter long? in Web API controller cause "no action was found on the controller..." error

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-web-api

The Web API works great but I don't understand why am I getting the "no action was found on the controller that matches the request error" exception error if I changed the parameter from "long parmAccountId" to "long? parmAccountId"?  (See the "?" next to long datatype).

Is there a way to make it work?  Thanks..

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "MemberApi",
            routeTemplate: "WebApi/Member/{controller}/{action}/{AccountId}/{UserId}",
            defaults: new { AccountId = RouteParameter.Optional, UserId = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
    }
}

public class DigitalLoanJacketController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("Upload")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(long? parmAccountId, long? parmUserId, Foo parmFoo)
    {
    }
}

//JQUery...
var jsonRequest = { "Id": 3, "Name": "Scott Fletcher"};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false, /*false, //This need to be synchronous to the client can wait for a webserver response...*/
    url: "https://localhost:44301/WebApi/Member/DigitalLoanJacket/Upload/e/83",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonRequest),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (parmData, parmTextStatus, parmXmlHttpRequest) {
        alert("AjaxStatus: " + parmTextStatus + "\nReadyState - " + parmXmlHttpRequest.readyState + "\nStatus: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.status + "\nStatusText: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.statusText + "\nResponseText: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.responseText);
    },
    error: function (parmXmlHttpRequest, parmTextStatus, parmErrorThrown) {
        alert("AjaxStatus: " + parmTextStatus + "\nReadyState - " + parmXmlHttpRequest.readyState + "\nStatus: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.status + "\nStatusText: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.statusText + "\nResponseText: " + parmXmlHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add code where you do the request to this action.

Comment: Here you go.  I don't see it what does it have to do with this exception error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem with your Post methd is, the parmAccountId and parmUserId would never get values from url. Because the accountId, UserId in the route template are different from parmAccountId,parmUserId in the post method. So, model binding will fail here, as it fills parameters by matching names.

Change parameter names in Post method. It would work.

```
Public string Post(long? accountId, long? userId, Foo parmFoo)
{

}
```

Model binding fills the method parameters by matching names.

This is the request flow in Web Api.

1. The routing mechanism fills the placeholders in route template from the url.
2. Next it matches action in controller, by type of request(Get, Post,Put...) and method parameters.
3. Next, model binding comes into picture and fills the method parameters by taking values from three places.They are route parameters, query string and request body.

Here model binding fills first two parameters(accountid, userId) in method from route parameters, and last parameter(Foo) from request body. Model binding fails to fill the first two parameters, because names does not match.

Comment: as was already mentioned by the author, you will get "Optional parameters must appear after all required parameter" in this case.

Comment: They are not optional parameters. They are nullable. If the optional parameters does not appear after required parameter. The compiler itself shows error.

Comment: sorry, I didn't pay attention that they are really nullable and not optional.

Comment: Guys...   Turned out @VikramBabu got it right.  I didnt know that parameter name & spelling must match for it to work.  Now I know it is what we called it "character sensitive" (like case sensitive) instead of parameter/arguement variables ordering as I thought it did.

Comment: Curious, is it possible to map the argument name to a different one?  If not then I'll have no trouble dealing with it.  Just that prefix naming help me to seperate variable name from long scripts.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED according to comment:**

Try to change you action declaration to:

```
public class DigitalLoanJacketController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("Upload")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(Foo parmFoo, long? parmAccountId = 0, long? parmUserId = 0)
    {
    }
}
```

or

```
public class DigitalLoanJacketController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("Upload")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(Foo parmFoo, long? parmAccountId = null, long? parmUserId = null)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...  I got a compiler error saying "Optional parameters must appear after all required parameter".   This is what I get when adding "= 0".

Comment: Is it a problem for you to change arguments positions? If no, look at new version of code in the answer.

Comment: hmmm.   Instead of changing the arguments position, it look like I will have to make parmAccountId & parmUserId to require a value, and not to be nullable.  :-/